# WHMCS Template modification

Tags: php, whmcs

On my WHMCS, the client is redirected to clientarea.php after signup, and I want them to be redirected to affiliates.php

Comment: So what's your question? And before you say, "how do I do it?", remember that questions like that are too broad and will be closed as such. So if you've written any code thus far I highly recommend adding it to your question. You should read "[how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: Bro , why being so presumptuous ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't had time to test but maybe this hook can be used:
https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/authentication/#clientlogin

Try if you can redirect when the hook is executed to affiliates.php and then break script execution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in the new version of WHMCS.

- Visit WHMCS Admin > Setup > General Settings > Other
- Now uncheck "Tick this box to skip the homepage and forward users
  directly to the client area/login form upon first visiting WHMCS"

hope this helps

Comment: That takes me to clientarea.php page

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **client_add hook** to redirect it to your own page. Details,

https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/client/#clientadd